# Check if $_GET is available and has specific value?

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I'm trying to check to see if a $_GET value is available AND equal to 1 but the error is that the index is not defined.

```
<?php if ((isset($_GET['success'])) ||  ($_GET['success'] == 1)) { ?>
Do Something
<?php } ?>
```

Why is this a problem? I'm checking to see if it exists and then if it equals one and if so , do something.

Is there a better way to achieve this goal?

Comment: If somebody's answer here helped, please accept / vote up their answer *rather than posting your own*

Comment: Understood cale_b... I wrote my own answer before/while the others were posted. People be fast around here :-)

Comment: Yes they are!  And I get it, just trying to help you out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the || (OR) to && (AND)

```
if ((isset($_GET['success'])) &&  ($_GET['success'] == 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

do this 
`<?php if (isset($_GET['success']) { if($_GET['success']==1){} ?>`

Do Something

`<?php } ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the OR for an AND in the conditional (&&)

Answer (score 0):

`||` = OR

`&&` = AND, which is what should have been used.